# How to send Email notifications from Firebase when database is updated

Tags: android, firebase, email, notifications

I am trying to see how I can make firebase send me email notifications whenever my firebase database/document gets updated. the database is used by my android app, and users have to signup/login, place an order, so I need to know when I have a new user signed up (which will reflect in firebase), and also I need to know when new orders are placed.

For now everything gets stored in firebase, but I need to know when there are new entries, I saw a thread on using nodemailer, but am not sure how exactly to implement that, so Ill need more clarification or a better way to get email notifications from firebase.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). Whenever your datastore is updated, a cloud function can be triggered, which in turn can send an automated email to user.

Here's a list of [triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) available on Firebase Realtime Database

And here's a sample which demonstrates sending automated email using firebase when database is updated: 
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users

Comment: I've gone through several tutorials like this and am wondering if this doesnt just deal with normal js apps, cos i dont see where its implemented for an android app

Comment: cloud functions are written in javascript/typescript and has nothing to do with android apps. They are triggered on firebase events like database update, auth, storage update etc, and these events can be created by any client like android, iOS, web app etc

Comment: Try this guide if you haven't, it will walk you through every step to deploy your first cloud function https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: Good now i have a clearer understanding, so where do i have to put this cloud functions? thats where i have an issue because i see people writing it in vs code, and that has nothing to do with what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: you will write your cloud function (using any editor/ide) and will upload/deploy to your firebase console project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase functions to trigger a function when your database is updated or user created : see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events or https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Then in your function, you can send you a mail with an email provider like sendgrid. Google "firebase functions send email" for tutorials.

Comment: basically it doesnt state where i get to put the firebase functions, and i can see that its in js, i need to know where i'll implement this function is it in firebase itself or localhost and also, how can i make it work with my app

Comment: Read firebase functions docs, these functions are running on google servers and are triggered automatically when something happens in your firebase project. Anyway, you can't send email client-side, so you can't send email on Android, you can only send emails server-side. The easiest way to do this is with firebase functions, you don't have to manage your server, just write your functions locally and send them in the cloud with firebase commande line. Read docs :)